# How to properly locate angular partial view

Tags: angularjs, express

I'm trying to follow a code example from PluralSite AngularJS fundamentals course.
After downloading the sample code, I have discovered that there is an issue with locating all of the partial views defined within the sample application.

The structure of the project is as follows:

```
DemoApp/app/partials
DemoApp/app/js/app.js
```

The first partial view that is not being found is:

```
GET http://myserver.mydomain.com:63342/partials/eventList.html 404 (Not Found)  eventList.html
```

Here is a snapshot of the OS path:

```
/Users/eugene/Documents/DevTraining/MeanStack/AngularJS/AngularJS Fundamentals/Demos/Original/DemoApp/app/partials/eventList.html
```

As you can see, the file is clearly there.

Here is how the routes are defined in `app.js`:

```
'use strict';

var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngResource']);
eventsApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/events', {templateUrl: '/partials/eventList.html', controller: 'EventListController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/events/:eventId/sessions/edit/:sessionId', {templateUrl: '/partials/editSession.html', controller: 'EditSessionController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/events/:eventId/sessions/new', {templateUrl: '/partials/editSession.html', controller: 'EditSessionController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/event/:eventId', {templateUrl: '/partials/event.html', controller: 'EventController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/events/new', {templateUrl: '/partials/editEvent.html', controller: 'EditEventController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/events/edit/:eventId', {templateUrl: '/partials/editEvent.html', controller: 'EditEventController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/register', {templateUrl: '/partials/editProfile.html', controller: 'EditProfileController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/editProfile', {templateUrl: '/partials/editProfile.html', controller: 'EditProfileController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/viewProfile/:userName', {templateUrl: '/partials/viewProfile.html', controller: 'ViewProfileController'});
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: '/partials/login.html', controller: 'LoginController'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/events'});
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  }]);
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: I think the issue is with your Express app configuration. Please post that as well.

Comment: I'm very new to this - what specific file outside of "app.js" represents Express config, please?

Comment: The `app.js` that you're showing is the client-side (Angular) code, not the server-side (Express) code. That's in another file (usually also called `app.js`, to make things more confusing ;).

Comment: I did the scan of the file system, but there was just one such file:  Eugenes-MacBook-Pro-3:AngularjS Fundamentals eugene$ find ./ -name app.js
.//Demos/Original/DemoApp/app/js/app.js
This makes me think, that Express may not even be involved in this demo app example. It may just be a straight-up Node on the back-end, just to support the running of the angular part.  I did find a web-server.js file, which makes no mention of Express. Perhaps, I should change the back-end (of now) to be just a bare-bones Express configuration, to help with troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there were two different issues here:

1. As pointed out by robertklep, something was wrong with my Express configuration. In fact, there was no Express configuration even involved - just a straight-up Node server to run the angular front-end example. To remedy that, I created the most based Express server:

   ```
   var express = require("express");
   var app = express();

   /* serves main page */
   app.get("/", function(req, res) {
       res.sendfile('index.html', { root: 'app' });
   });

   ///* serves all the static files */
   app.get(/^(.+)$/, function(req, res){
       console.log('static file request : ' + req.params);
       res.sendfile( __dirname + req.params[0]);
   });

   var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
   app.listen(port, function() {
       console.log("Listening on " + port);
   });
   ```

   This allowed me to start severing my index.html page, which, in turn, contains the angular tags and directives.
2. The other (i.e. original) issue of not having /partials mapped properly had to do with the fact of where the Express server process was started from.

Once I realized that, I placed my server script in the app directory, which allows to properly recognize the mapping of /partials, which, in turn, allowed for the angular partial fragments to be found and properly served. Now it works.